# Mapping values into two additional DataFrame columns by an existing one in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am making a generic tool which can take up any csv file.The file contains a city column which needs to be geocoded to latitudes and Longitudes. I have a csv file which looks something like this. The first row is the column name and the second row is the type of variable.

```
Time,M1,M2,M3,CityName
temp,num,num,num,loc
20-May-13,19,20,0,delhi
20-May-13,25,42,7,agra
20-May-13,23,35,4,mumbai
20-May-13,21,32,3,delhi
20-May-13,17,27,1,mumbai
20-May-13,16,40,5,delhi
```

First of all, I find the unique values in the City column and form a list of it.

```
filename = 'data_file.csv'
data_date = pd.read_csv(filename)
column_name = data_date.ix[:, data_date.loc[0] == "city"]
column_work = column_name.iloc[1:]
column_unique = column_work.iloc[:,3].unique().tolist()
```

Secondly, I have written code for geocoding my cities.

```
def geocode(address):
    i = 0
    try:
        while i < len(geocoders):
            # try to geocode using a service
            location = geocoders[i].geocode(address)

            # if it returns a location
            if location != None:

                # return those values
                return [location.latitude, location.longitude]
            else:
                # otherwise try the next one
                i += 1
    except:
        print (sys.exc_info()[0])
        return ['null','null']

    # if all services have failed to geocode, return null values
    return ['null','null']

list = ['delhi', 'agra', 'mumbai']
j = 0
lat = []
for row in list:
    print ('processing #',j)
    j+=1
    try:
        state = row
        address = state
        result = geocode(address)
        # add the lat/lon values to the row
        lat.extend(result)
    except:
       # print 'Unsuccessful'
       to_print = 'Unsuccessful'
       # row.extend(to_print)
       dout.append(row)
print(lat)
```

This gives me a list of latitudes and longitudes `[28.7040592, 77.10249019999999, 27.1766701, 78.00807449999999, 19.0759837, 72.8776559]`. I want to write this onto my CSV file as

```
Time,M1,M2,M3,CityName,Latitude,Longitude
temp,num,num,num,loc,lat,lng
20-May-13,19,20,0,delhi,28.7040592,77.10249019999999
20-May-13,25,42,7,agra,27.1766701,78.00807449999999
20-May-13,23,35,4,mumbai,19.0759837, 72.8776559
20-May-13,21,32,3,delhi,28.7040592,77.10249019999999
20-May-13,17,27,1,mumbai,19.0759837, 72.8776559
20-May-13,16,40,5,delhi,28.7040592,77.10249019999999
```

I tried making a separate list of latitudes and longitudes `latitude = lat[0::2] longitude = lat[1::2]` or convert it to into a dictionary `{'delhi': [28.7040592, 77.10249019999999], 'agra': [27.1766701, 78.00807449999999], 'mumbai': [19.0759837, 72.8776559]}` but somehow could not figure out how to write it on a csv file.

Comment: Do you need the "temp,num,num,num,loc,lat,lng" row in you csv file or DataFrame? I think it would be much easier if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I think converting them into a dictionary is a good approach.

```
dic = {'delhi': [28.7040592, 77.10249019999999],
       'agra': [27.1766701, 78.00807449999999],
       'mumbai': [19.0759837, 72.8776559]}

# Create new columns
data_date["Latitude"] = data_date.apply(lambda row: dic.get(row["CityName"])[0], axis = 1)
data_date["Longitude"] = data_date.apply(lambda row: dic.get(row["CityName"])[1], axis = 1)

# Write the data back to csv file
data_date.to_csv(filename, index = False)
```

In this way it gets values of corresponding city names from the dictionary, and write them into the specified column. Finally it overwrites the old csv file with the new data frame.